# Assignment of image in 0 and 1 using multidimensional array

Tags: java, android, multidimensional-array

I've this type of multidimensional array in Android. [image]

I want to display images just replacing this 0 and 1. where 0 for black image and 1 for red image. I tried the following code but which is not working. When I tried with A for 0 and B for 1, it works. But why black and red image. I don't understand.

Can anyone give any idea?
Thanks in Advance

```
  public void setImages() {
    try {

        int numArray[] = { 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1};
        shuffleList(numArray);

        for (i = 0; i <TwoArray.length - 1; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < TwoArray[i].length - 1; j++) {

                TwoArray[i][j] = numArray[a];
                a++;
                }
        }

        for (i = 0; i < TwoArray.length - 1; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < TwoArray[i].length - 1; j++) {

                if (TwoArray[i][j] == 0) {

                //black_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.black);
                    //System.out.print("A ");
                } else {
                    red_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.red);
                    //System.out.print("B ");
                }
                System.out.print(TwoArray[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

create an array of object like `red_img`, then `setImageResource` according to index properly.